# Javascript/jQuery undefined function error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am using a script for my slider called Camera. Unfortunately it keeps loading and gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('.camera_stop', camera_thumbs_wrap).live')
```

The piece of code where that is involved is as following: ( I have marked the line with error //> )

```
$('.camera_play', camera_thumbs_wrap).live('click', function() {
            autoAdv = true;
            elem.removeClass('paused');
//>         if ($('.camera_play', camera_thumbs_wrap).length) {
                $('.camera_play', camera_thumbs_wrap).hide();
                $('.camera_stop', camera_thumbs_wrap).show();
                if (loader != 'none') {
                    $('#' + pieID).show();
                }
            } else {
                if (loader != 'none') {
                    $('#' + pieID).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

My jQuery knowledge is not enough to fix this so I would be grateful if someone can tell me how to fix this :) I guess something may be colliding with another script perhaps?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did you comment out a line `//>`? Also, what's `elem`?

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using? It looks like the `live` function was deprecated in 1.7, and removed in 1.9. http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Also, what is `camera_thumbs_wrap`?

Comment: euh i am using v2.1.1

Comment: @j08691 He said he wanted to show us the line the error appears. I would do it behind the code Reshad.

Comment: Maybe not relevant to your answer, but `live()` is deprecated. Use `on()` instead - http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: It appears that the code displayed is not the same code causing the error.  The code has  `camera_play` and the error says `camera_stop`.

Comment: @marteljn that is the code shown to me by my console. Updating the camera slideshow to the newest version helped getting rid of that error but getting the same error now on the piece of code where I call the slider to play. jQuery('.camera_wrap').camera();

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the `live` function was deprecated in 1.7, and removed in 1.9. You should use `on` instead. See the jQuery docs for [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live) and [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I Found out there was a newer version of this slideshow and I got it installed but now the place I call it returns  the same error. jQuery('.camera_wrap').camera(); How do I solve this?

Comment: If you have a new question, please create a new question.

Answer (score -3):

You still have your `else` without your `if` , since it's commented

Comment: No that comment I just put here to show what line it goes wrong :) in my actual code there is no comment